# Ubuntu ISO download time

Tags: downloads, iso, time

I just downloaded a Ubuntu ISO today and wanted to see what time the file was downloaded. I tried viewing the file "properties" feature to see if it would tell me it. The file size, what directory it was saved in, etc. was displayed along with some times in military time format with the following lines:

**Accessed: Wed, Oct 18 2017 14:29:30**

**Modified: Wed, Oct 18 2017 14:29:29**

Are one of theses possibly the time I downloaded it? Is so, why are the two different because one is a second behind. I do not remember ever modifying the file what so ever. Thanks!

Comment: Generally, the file creation time is not easily available. The file's access, (data) modification and (metadata) change times are available. If the file was last modified at `Wed, Oct 18 2017 14:29:29` and you have never modified it, then it's probably the time when the last bits were downloaded into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Accessed*: the last time the file was read.
- *Modified*: the last time the file's content was modified.

Since you haven't modified the file yourself after downloading, the "*modified*' time should be the time when the download finished.

Comment: Is there a way I can check to see if this file was indeed "modified" or not?

Comment: @draculauseslinux2 Maybe you should ask a new question :) This community is pretty helpful and known for providing answers to proper queries.